# How to convert following CSV to Hashmap using JAVA

Tags: java, csv

Suppose I have CSV file like this:

```
Name    Roll No.    Address     PhoneNo
Jhon    909    CA       1
Jeff    101    CE       2
Jhon    121    US      3
Jhon    909    US      4
```

I want to generate output like this:

```
{Jhon={909={CA=[1],US=[4]},121={US=[3]}}, Jeff={101={CE=[2]}}}
```

All Jhon should group into 1 map and also if roll no. is same then it should also get group in same map.

Comment: Hi Snoop, Your question is a better fit for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I have to wait to ask next question in StackOverflow. I already asked one and have to wait for next one.

Comment: That is irrelevant. Worse, that is circumventing limits that are in place for a reason. I have voted to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a list in a map in map to do this. 
The first map has the key to the name and the inner map has the key to the roll.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>> persons = new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<Person>>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("stuff.csv")));
        br.readLine(); //Skip the header line
        while(br.ready()){
            add(new Person(br.readLine()));
        }
        System.out.println(persons);
    }

    private static void add(Person person) {
        if(!persons.containsKey(person.getName())){
            persons.put(person.getName(), new HashMap<String, List<Person>>());
        }
        if(!persons.get(person.getName()).containsKey(person.getRoll())){
            persons.get(person.getName()).put(person.getRoll(), new ArrayList<Person>());
        }
        persons.get(person.getName()).get(person.getRoll()).add(person);
    }

    static class Person {

        String name, roll, address, phone;

        public Person(String string) {
            final StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(string, " ", false);
            name = tok.nextToken();
            roll = tok.nextToken();
            address = tok.nextToken();
            phone = tok.nextToken();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getRoll() {
            return roll;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return address + "=[" + phone + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
{Jeff={101=[CE=[2]]}, Jhon={121=[US=[3]], 909=[CA=[1], US=[4]]}}
```

Comment: One more thing, I wanted convert this value into JSONObject like:       name: and children: pair.

Comment: You could use jackson like this: `JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(persons);`

Comment: That will create simple json but wanted to generate JSON format which will generate the input for D3.js

Comment: If you add get methods for address and phone in the Person class and add the line `System.out.println(new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().valueToTree(persons));` below the other system out println and add a reference to the jackson jar files the output will be: `{"Jeff":{"101":[{"name":"Jeff","roll":"101","address":"CE","phone":"2"}]},"Jhon":{"121":[{"name":"Jhon","roll":"121","address":"US","phone":"3"}],"909":[{"name":"Jhon","roll":"909","address":"CA","phone":"1"},{"name":"Jhon","roll":"909","address":"US","phone":"4"}]}}`
 This can be directly used as data to your javascript.